# Is it realistic to use a CDN with low traffic numbers?

Tags: cdn, akamai, esi

I have an application that I'd like to host on a CDN with edge side includes, even though I have relatively low web traffic.  Is this possible with the big name CDNs, like Akamai, or would they just tell me to get lost?  And how much would it cost?  MaxCDN looks like a good first step but I don't think they can do edge side includes.

Comment: They wouldn't tell you to get lost. It might be a bit above your budget, but if you're low traffic then they get a big payment for handling relatively little traffic. Pricing depends partly on traffic and partly what options you add in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a CDN?  Can you do what you want with Varnish and ESI?

What problem do you have that makes you want to use a CDN in the first place? If you really do need a CDN and your traffic is low, they won't tell you to 'get lost', they will hopefully point you in the direction of one of their resellers.